# Add Reserved IP to Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service in Azure that I want to give a reserved IP to.  I basically followed the steps here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

I performed the "New-AzureReservedIP" cmd, giving an ip name of "MyIPName" and a location of the East US - the same location of my current cloud service.

In my service config, I used the following:

```
    <NetworkConfiguration>
        <AddressAssignments>
        <ReservedIPs>
        <ReservedIP name="MyIPName"/>
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

When I attempted to deploy my cloud service, I got the error "The Reserved IP MyIPName does not exist.  Although I just created it, its not recognizing my aptly named reserved ip address.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working now.  2 things happened on my end.

1. Father Time eventually passed, I think it took some time from the Azure side to recognize that this Reserved IP was created and that my subscription had a reserved IP named MyIPName
2. When I published my cloud service, I used Visual Studio 2013, and in the publish settings I chose "Advanced Settings", checked the "Deployment update" checkbox, chose Settings next to that checkbox, and chose "If deployment can't be updated, do a full deployment".  That allowed the VM instances to be recreated with the Reserved IP Address applied.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It has been about 20 hours since setting up the Reserved IP address. How long do you suppose it will take?

Comment: Hey @andrewdudek84 I hope the IP is available for you by now.  If not, I would make sure that you created the IP in the correct account.  I'd also use powershell to check what reserved IP's youve provisioned, and make sure youre spelling the name of the reserved IP correctly in your config (check for leading and trailing spaces!).  Sorry.. best of luck..

Comment: Well, my guy who assigned the IP address assigned it to the wrong Azure subscription. Working now, thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem after creating a Reserved IP through the Azure Portal. The answer from June 2015 did not work for me. For me the solution was to use Powershell to connect to the Azure subscription and then get the FULL name of the Reserved IP and use it in the service config.  The full name of my Reserved IP was in the format "Group {Resource Name} {Reserved IP Name}".

Publishing from Visual Studio 2013 then worked.

To confirm that this wasn't a timing issue I then tried again using only the {Reserved IP Name} value and found that it still did not work (ie received Error: The Reserved IP xyz does not exist.).  Hence it would seem that the full Reserved IP name must be used when it has been created from the Azure Portal and then publishing from Visual Studio.

Note: I am using a Classic app service.

Comment: You should ask a new question about your issue. Don't ask in an answer.

Comment: Hi Walter, I think that it is appropriate to put an updated answer in here as it would seem that the previous answer to this issue no longer works.  This could save people some frustration.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: No problem.  :-)

Comment: This worked for me as well, the key is that the name created by azure portal is not exactly the same as a user has entered while creating.

Comment: Worked for me. Oddly though, it used to work previously without the "long name" required.